# Updating json field in objectionjs throws Unknown column 'lng' in 'field list

Tags: node.js, nestjs, knex.js, objection.js

I have a nestjs app where I am using objectionjs and knex to communicate with my mysql db.
The address field is a json like:

```
data = {
   address: { lat: 12, lng: 20 }
}
```

Whenever I run an update using:

```
this.personRepository
      .query()
      .update(data)
      .where('id', person.id)
      .execute()
```

I keep getting this error-
Unknown column 'lng' in 'field list'

Full error is something like:

```
update `persons` set `address` = {"lat":12,"lng":20}, `updatedAt` = '2023-02-28 23:27:39.476' where `id` = X'1234567'
```

Please help me point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you need to [stringify](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) the variable `data`

Comment: @TobokSitanggang I thought about this, but since I'm using typescript and the model is typed to json on different parts of the code, stringify just sends me down a rabbit hole that feels very hacky to fix by changing the type in every place where this field appears.

Comment: i got you, i suggest to use type any only for this attribute if there are too much needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON fields should be automatically stringified by objection by defining the jsonSchema `address` property as an object.

```
class Person extends Model {
  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        address: { 
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            lat: { type: 'number' },
            lng: { type: 'number' },
          },
        },
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you don't have a schema by setting the [`jsonAttributes`](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-properties.html#static-jsonattributes) property on the Model.

```
class Person extends Model {
  static get jsonAttributes() {
    return ['address'];
  }
}
```